# Avoid writing multiple lines (same piece of code) by using a one line function

Tags: python, loops, optimization

I would like to write the below piece of code in one line.
All 9 lines are same (except the column name, ex: Two, Three, Four, etc.,)

Below is my code:
Note: 'df' is my data frame name.

```
df['Two'] = df['Two'].map(lambda x: re.sub(r'\W+', ' ', x))
df['Three'] = df['Three'].map(lambda x: re.sub(r'\W+', ' ', x))
df['Four'] = df['Four'].map(lambda x: re.sub(r'\W+', ' ', x))
df['Five'] = df['Five'].map(lambda x: re.sub(r'\W+', ' ', x))
df['Six'] = df['Six'].map(lambda x: re.sub(r'\W+', ' ', x))
df['Seven'] = df['Seven'].map(lambda x: re.sub(r'\W+', ' ', x))
df['Eight'] = df['Eight'].map(lambda x: re.sub(r'\W+', ' ', x))
df['Nine'] = df['Nine'].map(lambda x: re.sub(r'\W+', ' ', x))
df['Ten'] = df['Ten'].map(lambda x: re.sub(r'\W+', ' ', x))
```

I tried for loop but I was able to loop only integers, not able to get column names in the loop.
I need one line of code to execute all these lines. Because in the future the column may increase and I can not keep adding lines.

Comment: `for name in ['Two', 'Three', ...]:`...

Answer (score 0):

`df.columns` holds the column names of the df object. So iterate over the column names, dynamically select each column with `df[col]` and apply your `map` function.

```
for col in df.columns:
    df[col]=df[col].map(lambda x: re.sub(r'\W+', ' ', x))
```

Comment: Code-only answers may resolve the question, but do not help people with this problem in understanding why the code resolves their issue. Please edit your answer and explain why this code solves the problem.